# How to ask for removing user data while uninstall application?

Tags: c#, windows, installshield-2013

I use InstallShield Limited version 2013 to configure setup of my Visual Basic application. I save application user data.

Usually Uninstallation does not remove files of application.

While Uninstallation, I want to delete files with an alert of "Do you want to delete profile folder?".

Can anybody please suggest me way to achieve this?

Comment: InstallShield only supports the creation of custom UI in the Professional and higher editions (custom actions may be able to get close in lower editions). That said, this sort of thing is typically discouraged as it's only possible to remove the current user's settings this way, and conditional deletion of any kind is difficult with Windows Installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstaller doesn't delete things which has been modified/added by user. Because such added files doesn't present in File table of uninstaller.

To remove such files, create CustomAction. In CustomAction you can show MessageBox & accordinly you can delete a specific folder or files using Delete function.

Add this CustomAction in your execution sequence & set condition of "REMOVE=ALL", So it will execute only at uninstallation.